# If according to Quran, Allah does not charge a soul except [with that within] its capacity then why people die out of pain?

Tags: tafseer, surat-al-baqarah

Could someone explain me the last verses of Surah Baqarah: https://quran.com/2/286

Keeping in view of this verse, Why there is severe pain and miseries in our lives?

Seeking explanation and clarity...

Comment: I am not sure how severe pain has anything to do with the verse. Can't it be within people's capacity to bear pain?

Comment: How do you know that, their pain and miseries are not in their capacity?

Comment: @DavidHarry People die simply because they are not able to bear the pain! This is a scientifically proved and accepted fact!

Comment: The question is why souls are subjected to extreme pain? The extreme pain which is not in their capacity to be tolerated. And once again, it has been a common observation that the pious and honest usually suffers much more than the evil and dishonest. Tell me if I am wrong. If Allah is not taking about burden than what else Allah is meant to say? Allah does subject pure and innocent souls to extreme pain and torture!!! I ask you: why innocent newborns die out of starvation in African countries stricken by famine???

Comment: @Maxood Pain and death is not the thing here. Burden here means I believe, the pain or the test will not be so much that a person have to leave his Iman or sell out his Iman. And Allah tests those he loves. That's why pious people suffers. Because people remember Allah in differently, people comes more closer to allah in difficult situation. But that are in their capacity. Different people get tested in different ways by what they can bear. And those people will get their full reward of what they had suffered. And our whole life is a test.

Answer (score 2):

> لاَ يُكَلِّفُ اللَّهُ نَفْسًا إِلاَّ وُسْعَهَا
>
> (Allah burdens not a person beyond his scope)

Means, Allah does not ask a soul what is beyond its ability. This only demonstrates Allah's kindness, compassion and generosity towards His creation. This Ayah is the Ayah that abrogated the Ayah that worried the Companions, that is, Allah's statement,

> وَإِن تُبْدُواْ مَا فِي أَنفُسِكُمْ أَوْ تُخْفُوهُ يُحَاسِبْكُم بِهِ
> اللَّهُ
>
> (And whether you disclose what is in yourselves or conceal it, Allah
> will call you to account for it.)

This indicates that although Allah will question His servants and judge them, He will only punish for what one is able to protect himself from. As for what one cannot protect himself from, such as what one says to himself - or passing thoughts - they will not be punished for that. We should state here that to dislike the evil thoughts that cross one's mind is a part of faith.

Source: [Tafsir Ibn Kathir](http://www.alim.org/library/quran/AlQuran-tafsir/TIK/2/285)

Answer (score 0):

The pain while death is based on you deeds. If the dying person is a Kafir the death angel will take his soul very Harshly and he have great pain. On the other a believer's soul is taken out easily and he would fell like a bite of an ant. If he was a believer and did good deeds in his lifetime Allah won't give him too much pain while death. Allah knows the best.